# How to add constraint on equal types in Rust?

Tags: rust, constraints, traits

I have to add a constraint over a struct defined by me.
In particular this struct works with a generic called T which has two types: Input and Output. I want to set a constraint on which the type of the Input is the same of the type of Output.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Example<T>
{
... // fields of the struct
}
```

In other words since I work either with T::Input and T::Output, I have some cases in which the Output of a struct A is the Input of a struct B and clearly this is a problem in compilation time because the error I get is:
`expected T::Input, found T::Output` so the arguments are incorrect.
Actually I understand what is the problem, but I do not know how to explain what I want to do to the compiler.

I have tried to add the constraints using the `where` clause trying to specify that "T::Input = T::Output", but they did not work.
I tried to do something like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Example<T>
where
    T::Input: From<T::Output>,
    T::Output: From<T::Input>

{
... // fields of the struct
}
```

Comment: @kmdreko You're right, I read the question too fast.

Answer (score 4):

As kmdreko's answer comments, the straightforward way to write this would be something like:

```
trait InOut {
    type Input;
    type Output;
}

struct Example<T> where T: InOut<Input = T::Output> {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately this fails with that weird circular dependency error.

But sometimes, when you use an associated type in a generic type parameter, it is required to be written fully, or some ambiguity error happens. In this case, instead of `T::Output` you need to write `<T as InOut>::Output`:

```
trait InOut {
    type Input;
    type Output;
}

struct Example<T> where T: InOut<Input = <T as InOut>::Output> {
    ...
}
```

And this [just works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=222c170d3422104542beef90d4f00eb5).

My guess about why the former fails and the latter works is the following: When you write `T::Output` the compiler does not what trait this `Output` comes from, so it has to check all the implemented traits, but wait... what traits does it implement? it It doesn't know, yet, so it enters an infinite loop. But if you write `<T as InOut>::Output` it does not have to check all the traits, it just have to implement `InOut` and that is already assumed when it is evaluating this condition, so all goes well.

Comment: It worked perfectly in this case!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the naive solution doesn't work:

```
trait InOut {
    type Input;
    type Output;
}

struct Example<T> where T: InOut<Input = T::Output> {
    ...
}
```

```
error[E0391]: cycle detected when computing the bounds for type parameter `T`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:42
  |
6 | struct Example<T> where T: InOut<Input = T::Output> {
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: ...which immediately requires computing the bounds for type parameter `T` again
note: cycle used when computing explicit predicates of `Example`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:42
  |
6 | struct Example<T> where T: InOut<Input = T::Output> {
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

However, I was able to make it work with an additional trait that implements the original trait if the types match:

```
trait InOut {
    type Input;
    type Output;
}

trait InAndOut: InOut<Input = Self::Item, Output = Self::Item> {
    type Item;
}

impl<T, I> InAndOut for T where T: InOut<Input = I, Output = I> {
    type Item = I;
}

struct Example<T> where T: InAndOut {
    ...
}
```

Full example available on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6ed7e27b843509b5b6be169b2f1055c6).

Comment: I thought about this (even posted an answer), but this won't help: if you have methods that require (or give back) `T::Input` (or the opposite), you will not be able to give them `T::Output`, because rustc is unable to deduce from this implementation that the type will _always_ be the same. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0667cb4076f695776051fc6031348725.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2158a78813a912e3417af9874f3859d) seems to work... Though I can see other situations where it might not.

Comment: But the cycle error can be fixed by writing `where T: InOut<Input = <T as InOut>::Output>`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=222c170d3422104542beef90d4f00eb5).

Comment: @rodrigo ah nice, you could probably post that as your own answer since that looks the simplest

Comment: Ok, posted ;-).